# Convert a string in a list into an atom

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So, I have a list of strings inside a map, like this:

```
%{select =>  ["status_id", "first_name"]}.
```

I want to convert it into an **atom** inside a list, like this:

```
[:status_id, :first_name].
```

Using something like:

```
String.to_existing_atom
```

but that function takes one argument, not a list.

I could not find a way to do it in a list. Is it possible, through some built in function?

How can I do it?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Map.update!/3` to update a value inside a map and then `Enum.map/2` to map the list over `String.to_existing_atom/1`:

```
iex(1)> :status_id
:status_id
iex(2)> :first_name
:first_name
iex(3)> map = %{:select => ["status_id", "first_name"]}
%{select: ["status_id", "first_name"]}
iex(4)> map2 = Map.update!(map, :select, fn list -> Enum.map(list, &String.to_existing_atom/1) end)
%{select: [:status_id, :first_name]}
```

Comment: Thanks `Enum.map`.Thats what i am looking for

Answer (score 2):

I would use two simple functions to transform it.
First let's put map into a variable.

```
map = %{:select =>  ["status_id", "first_name"]}
```

And then just:

```
map
|> Map.get(:select) 
|> Enum.map(fn(x) -> String.to_atom(x) end)
```

It returns:

```
[:status_id, :first_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Kernel.update_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#update_in/3) and [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) come to the rescue:

```rb
iex(1)> foo = %{select: ~w|status_id first_name|}
#⇒ %{select: ["status_id", "first_name"]}
iex(2)> update_in foo, ~w|select|a, fn e ->
...(2)>   Enum.map(e, &String.to_atom/1)
...(2)> end
#⇒ %{select: [:status_id, :first_name]}
```